# Huawei D16 r5 no sound 22.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

I'm new in Ubuntu Linux and I have a big problem. After I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Huawei matebook D16 r5, I don't get any sound in my computer.

I just tried all things that I found on Internet, but nothing works.

Here is more information about my computer, drivers and more specific to my problem. I hope you can help me. I don't want to go back to Windows.

```
fernu@fernu-dev:~$ inxi -A
Audio:
Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-42-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

This is my `lspci -v`

```
3:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High        Definition Audio Controller
Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 73, IOMMU group 4
Memory at d03c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

my `aplay -l` output:

```
fernu@fernu-dev:~$ aplay -l
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdispositivos: 1/1
Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdispositivos: 1/1
Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdispositivos: 1/1
Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
```

This is my audio config:
[image: This is my audio config.]

The audio card is detected, but doesn't work:
[image: The audio card is detected, but doesn't work.]